# Replication Issue in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication

While launching replication monitor and creating publisher by Add Publisher Link in sql server 2008 I am getting following errors :-

```
**Server is neither Publisher not a distributor , or you do not have permission to access replication functionality in this server.**
```

User I am using for this replication have sysadmin and all other required permissions for this server so I am unable to find what is causing this issue

Kindly help me to sort out this issue

Comment: If you want to create a new publication, you do it by Right-clicking the Replication folder, choosing New, and selecting Publication. The Add Publisher link in Replication Montior is described as "add a publisher to **monitor**" (my emphasis) and is intended to be used to access an existing publication. Can you clarify which of these you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @@Damien_The_Unbeliever: When I click on Replication folder and choosing New than no option is present there for Publication and only option available there is for subscription. What I need to make publication option available

Comment: Then it sounds like your on a server edition that doesn't support being a publisher, i.e. Express.

Comment: I guess yes as currently I am working in sql server 2008 express

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.100).aspx). Express only supports being a subscriber, not a publisher or distributor.